# Xamarin Android: Can I not create a new object of my MainActivity?

Tags: object, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a location mocking method in my main activity. Unfortunately, I cant put this method into another class (yet!). So, I need a service, to call this method from my main activity every 5 seconds. So i created a countdown in within a service that, while the app is in the background, should run the method in my MainActivity. But it doesnt.

```
    public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Info("2", "CountDown ausgeführt!");
        var test = new MainActivity();

        test.getMockLocation();

    }
```

This is my code. As you can see, I'm installing a new object of my Main Activity and then ask for the method in within this activity. This does work. Well at least Visual Studio does not complain. If I now debug my app on my phone, nothing happens. I dont get no errors or anything. 
Now, when I run this app Step by Step and it reaches this point
"var test = new MainActivity();"

I get "Frame not in Module".

So, it basically crashes as soon as I ask it to install a new object of my Main Activity. 
May anybody tell me why this is? 
THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Android you cannot create Activities like this, they need to be instantiated by the OS. Also, instantiate a whole Activity only for a method is not ideal, I suggest you to find the way to get that method/function out of that Activity so you can use it anywhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your app via Xamarin Forms? If you did, you can utilize the Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter for background services and then you can call your mock location tasks.

This is the [link](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/) for a very helpful walk-through and example of MessagingCenter.